# Why Swagger @ApiModelProperty shows up on getters instead of the attributes in the model classes?

Tags: java, swagger, javadoc, swagger-codegen

When using swagger code generator (swagger-codegen-cli) from yaml file, I followed instructions in https://swagger.io/docs/open-source-tools/swagger-codegen/ and generated Java code using

```
java -jar swagger-codegen-cli-2.2.1.jar generate -i <path of your Swagger specification> -l java
```

After the code gets generated, `@ApiModelProperty` (with the description) shows up on getters instead of the attributes in the model classes. 
How can i configure it to show on the attributes?